# Express, Jade, & NodeJS: Navigate between pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

How do I create a Jade page that has two buttons where each one of them redirects to another page made with Jade?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the code I made for your question:

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express(); 

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('layout', {
    title: 'Home'
  });
});

app.get('/newpage', function(req, res){
  res.render('anotherpage', {
    title: 'Home'
  });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

**page1.jade**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    p hi there!
    button(onclick="move()") newPage
script.
  function move() {
    window.location.href = '/newpage'
  }
```

**anotherpage.jade**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    p welcome to the other page!
```

Enjoy, because it took me 15 minutes to write all this and the post.

Luca

Comment: I implemented above script but it doesn't invoke the move() function onclick event, how to solve it.

Comment: in some Mac navigators, you need to return false on click. onclick="move(); return false;"

Comment: @ipinyol your comment solved my > 6 hours desperation... Thank you

Comment: What's relation between `res.render('layout', {
    title: 'Home'
  });` and page `page1.jade` . I think may be you mistake here. you have to write `page1` instead of `layout`.

Comment: Is this really the cleanest way to do so? Why not simply use the html link element?  Instead of `button(onclick="move()") newPage` >>  `a(href="/newpage")="New Page"`. Like that, no need to add the `move()` function.